# Access Multiple Owners one record

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, relational-database

First Database has the following:

OwnerID, FName, LName

Second Database has the following:

OwnerID,PolicyName, Owner2ID,Owner3ID,Owner4ID,Owner5ID, Owner6ID, Owner7ID

So there are multiple owners for a particular policy.  My question is how can I design a query in Access that will return all the rows for each policy that have more than one owner.  For example assume policy one has OwnerID,Owner2ID,Owner3ID filled with ID based on the first database.  How can I return:

OwnerID, Policy Name
Owner2ID,POlicy Name
Owner3ID,Policy Name

So same policy name but because that one record as multiple owners, it will list all of them in a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first normalise you data, you can run any number of queries:

```
SELECT a.policyname,
   a.ownerid
FROM   (SELECT policyname,
           ownerid
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner2id
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner3id
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner4id
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner5id
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner6id
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner7id
    FROM   policies) AS a;
```

For example, here is a count:

```
SELECT a.policyname,
   Count(a.ownerid) AS CountOfOwnerID
FROM   (SELECT policyname,
           ownerid
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner2id
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner3id
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner4id
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner5id
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner6id
    FROM   policies
    UNION ALL
    SELECT policyname,
           owner7id
    FROM   policies) AS a
WHERE (((a.OwnerID) Is Not Null))
GROUP BY a.PolicyName;
```

You can also save the "flat" query and refer to the saved query to build other, more complex queries.